# UPDATE IS NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

This is my index page ,data fetching is working but update table is not working, can you please help me to slove this problem.

**IndexPage**

```
<script>
jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid({
url:'server.php',
datatype: "json", 
   colModel:[ 
   {name:'WeekNo',index:'WeekNo', width:30 , editable:false,editrules : { required: false}}, 
   {name:'WeekBeginning',index:'WeekBeginning', width:100 ,editable:true,editrules : { required: true}}, 
   {name:'SITE',index:'SITE', width:40 , editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'Name',index:'Name', width:150,align:"center" , editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'WFH',index:'WFH', width:40, classes: 'cvteste', editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'Login',index:'Login', width:80, editable:true,editrules : { required: false}},
   {name:'Manager_Login',index:'Manager_Login', width:90 , editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'Lead',index:'Lead', width:70, editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'Cost_center',index:'Cost_center', width:70, editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'Business_Title',index:'Business_Title', width:100, editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'Function',index:'Function', width:70, editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'Workgroup',index:'Workgroup', width:70, editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'Login_time',index:'Login_time', width:70, editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'ROLE',index:'ROLE', width:70,editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'Secondary_Skill',index:'Secondary_Skill', width:90, editable:true,editrules : { required: true}},
   {name:'Weekoff',index:'Weekoff', width:60, editable:true,editrules : { required: true}}     
   ],

rowNum:100,
rowList:[100,200,300],
pager: '#prowed2',
//sortname: ('WeekNo','Name') ,
viewrecords: true,
height:'500px',
sortorder: "asc",
gridComplete: function(){
    var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
        var cl = ids[i];
        be = "<input style='height:22px;width:40px;' type='button' value='Edit' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').jqGrid('editRow','"+cl+"');\"  />"; 
        se = "<input style='height:22px;width:40px;' type='button' value='Save' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').jqGrid('saveRow','"+cl+"');\"  />"; 
        ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Cancel' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').jqGrid('restoreRow','"+cl+"');\" />"; 
        jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:be+se+ce});
    }   
},
editurl: "update.php"
});
jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('navGrid',"#prowed2{edit:true,add:true,del:true});

var timeoutHnd; 
var flAuto = true;
function doSearch(ev){ 
 if(!flAuto)return; 
 if(timeoutHnd) clearTimeout(timeoutHnd);
  timeoutHnd = setTimeout(gridReload,500);
 } 
function gridReload(){
 var nm_mask = jQuery("#login").val();
 var cd_mask = jQuery("#man").val();
 var func = jQuery("#func").val();
jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"server.php?   nm_mask="+nm_mask+"&cd_mask="+cd_mask+"&func="+func,page:1}).trigger("reloadGrid");

}          
     </script>
```

Here if i use WeekNo at WHERE condition it is showing error undefined variable so im not using WeekNo then it is not updating database not even generating log file.

**UpdatePage**

```
    <?php


 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "DB");  


//This contains the data that will update the db
//$WeekNo = $_POST['WeekNo'];
$WeekBeginning = $_POST['WeekBeginning'];
$SITE = $_POST['SITE'];
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$WFH = $_POST['WFH'];
//$Login = $_POST['Login'];
$Manager_Login = $_POST['Manager_Login'];
$Lead = $_POST['Lead'];
$Cost_center = $_POST['Cost_center'];
$Business_Title = $_POST['Business_Title']; 
$Function = $_POST['Function'];
$Workgroup = $_POST['Workgroup'];
$Login_time = $_POST['Login_time'];
$ROLE = $_POST['ROLE'];
$Secondary_Skill = $_POST['Secondary_Skill'];
$Weekoff = $_POST['Weekoff'];

$sql = "UPDATE EmpMasterTB SET WeekBeginning='$WeekBeginning', SITE='$SITE', Name ='$Name', WFH='$WFH', Manager_Login='$Manager_Login', Lead='$Lead', Cost_center='$Cost_center', Business_Title='$Business_Title', Function='$Function', Workgroup='$Workgroup', Login_time='$Login_time', ROLE='$ROLE', Secondary_Skill='$Secondary_Skill', Weekoff='$Weekoff' WHERE ROLE = $_POST[ROLE] AND Login = $_POST[Login]";

 mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
 mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: any error you get?

Comment: uncomment the `//$WeekNo = $_POST['WeekNo'];`]

Comment: No error, but data is not updating

Comment: if i uncomment it ,it is showing error like undefined variable so thats what im not using  **WeekNo** variable may be **WeekNo** have link with index.php please check guys and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` condition for your `UPDATE` query should be:

```
WHERE ROLE = '$_POST[ROLE]' AND login = '$_POST[Login]'
```

When binding variables, especially string type, you should be using ticks (`'`) to incorporate them in your query.

Also, use [`*_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) before you bind them to your query.

```
$role = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ROLE"]);
```

Do the rest for the `POST` submitted data.

Comment: please explain little about `mysqli_real_escape_string     `$role = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ROLE"]);` in where condition can i use like this  `WHERE ROLE = '$role'`         @Logan

Comment: and how cani add delete record code can i use `delurl:'delete.php'` like this

Comment: Click the link in my answer to read further about `*_real_escape_string`. Yes, you will change again the `WHERE` condition to `WHERE ROLE = '$role'`. For your add/delete question, you can post another question. Or search here in SO or Google if a similar question is already posted.